# my own id in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I tried to change the standard 'id' in grails:

```
calls Book {
  String id
  String title

  static mapping {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }
}
```

unfortunately, I soon noticed that this breaks my bootstrap. Instead of

```
new Book (id:'some ISBN', title:'great book').save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

I had to use

```
def b = new Book(title:'great book')
b.id = 'some ISBN'
b.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

otherwise I get an 'ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()' error.

but that's ok so far.

I then encountered the same problem in the save action of my bookController. But this time, the workaround didn't do the trick.

Any suggestions?

I known, I can rename the id, but then I will have to change all scaffolded views...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a feature of databinding. You don't want submitted data to be able to change managed fields like `id` and `version`, so the Map constructor that you're using binds all available properties except those two (it also ignores any value for `class`, `metaClass`, and a few others).

So there's a bit of a mismatch here since the value isn't managed by Hibernate/GORM but by you. As you saw the workaround is that you need to create the object in two steps instead of just one.

Comment: Ok. That explains the bootstrap. But how do I set the ID in the controller? Somehow, the same workaround didn't work? Or did I something wrong while I debugged? Will retry tomorrow...

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem, but your work around doesn't work for me.

Comment: For future reference, this was fixed with the [bindable](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html) constraint which I believe came about in Grails 2.2+. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 7):

I can't replicate this problem (used Grails 2.0.RC1). I think it might be as simple as a missing equal sign on your static mapping = {  (you just have static mapping {)

Here's the code for a domain object:

```
class Book {
    String id
    String name

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'               
    }
}
```

And inside BootStrap.groovy:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    new Book(name:"test",id:"123abc").save(failOnError:true)
}
```

And it works fine for me. I see the id as 123abc.

Comment: thanx. I guess I have to double-check this.

Comment: Have you defined your `Book` domain in some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [bindable](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html) constraint to `true` for your id prop, e.g.

```
class Employee {
    Long id
    String name

    static constraints = {
        id bindable: true
    }
}
```