# Assigned domain class id wierdness with Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to set the id manually on grails 1.3.7

This compiles but the id is always 0

```
//in bootstrap
def it1 = new ItemType(id:4,name:'feature')
it1.save()
//domanin class
class ItemType {
    String name
    int id

    static constraints = {
        id(unique:true,blank:false)
        name(blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'ItemTypeId', generator:'assigned'
        name column: 'Name'
        version false
    }
}
```

This compiles and id 4 (as required)

```
//in bootstrap
def it1 = new ItemType(name:'feature')
it1.id=4
it1.save()
//domanin class
class ItemType {
    String name
    //int id

    static constraints = {
        id(unique:true,blank:false)
        name(blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'ItemTypeId', generator:'assigned'
        name column: 'Name'
        version false
    }
}
```

So my question is there a way to have id as prop but assigned?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem a few days ago: [my own id in GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919634/my-own-id-in-gorm)

It seems that it is a feature :-)